# OpenCV:Whats the easiest way to divide a Mat by a Scalar

Tags: c++, opencv

I think it's pretty much in the title, obviously I can iterate through and divide. But I assume there is an inbuilt way. I saw `cvConvertScale` but this does not work with type `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I know the scaling operation for a multiplication by a scalar:

```
cv::Mat M;
float alpha;
cv::Mat Result = M * alpha;
```

Let's try this:

```
cv::Mat Result = M / alpha;
```

Or:

```
float beta = 1.0f / alpha;
cv::Mat Result = M * beta;
```

Comment: hmm thanks, my IDE wasn't showing operator/ or operator* which is why I didn't try this.

Comment: What is the type of Result Mat if mat M is CV_8UC3? does it automatically become CV_32FC3 ?