# There is an unclear issue in scaling and subtracting an image using OpenCV 3 C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

So I've generated a binary jpeg image as shown here :

[image]

as I know this image has either 255 or 0 values (I dunno why in paint I find some pixels at the edge with different values, but I ignored them they are so few, and I am not sure if they came from the JPEG format)

so my target is to convert this image to 0x00 for the dark spots and 0x01 for the light spots (note I mean 1 as one and not as 255)

```
for (int i = 0; i < eroded_dilated_binary.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < eroded_dilated_binary.cols; j++)
    {
        pix=eroded_dilated_binary.at<char>(i, j); //pix is defined as char here
        eroded_dilated_binary.at<char>(i, j)  = (pix / 255);
    }
}
```

out is here : 
[image]

I checked the output and I got to deduce it is all 0's. but how is it possible?
I even tried to divide the first image by 2 I got non-logical answer. I even tried to subtract some value from each pixel but still got weird values.

I tried that other syntax shown in this topic [OpenCV:Whats the easiest way to divide a Mat by a Scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438293/opencvwhats-the-easiest-way-to-divide-a-mat-by-a-scalar)  but it gives totally wrong values.

1-What is going on behind the scenes? I don't get how arithmetic operations work here!!

2- how to guarantee that my image is only 1's and 0's or only 0's and 255's?

3- when I and this binary mask with the original image to hide the background, I get the middle image correctly but the body of the bottle has more fluctuations and random pixilization in the middle and even Gaussian filter is not smoothing well. I thought anding function has different way of working too?

Comment: should be `uchar`, not `char`

Comment: don't use jpeg, it's lossy and leads to weird values. use a lossless compression method like png instead.

Comment: Can you show the declarations of `pix` and `eroded_dilated_binary`?

Comment: @A.E.Drew char pix=0;  
Mat eroded_dilated_binary;